# Using skype-java-api on a x64 system

Tags: java, skype, skype4java

I'm using *skype-java-api* to use skype in Java. The only feature that i need is to dial phone numbers on click. It works fine on windows XP x86, but i just tested it on a Windows 7 x64, and it fails. The error is:
***Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Vazdautan\AppData\Local\Temp\skype.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform***

 Are there any other cross-platform alternatives(for MAC and Windows) or is it possible to solve it somehow ?

Thanks, Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS.

If you want to run a 64-bit JVM, you can use this to run a 32-bit JVM either as a service or on an ad-hoc basis.e.g. With Runtime.exec()

Or Skype provide a 64-bit DLL in which case I would just use that.

Comment: I will bundle a x86 java platform with it using launch4j. Thanks for the idea.