# JNIConnector.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform Skype4java

Tags: java

okay, so I am using the *skype4java* api in netbeans. I have added the .jar to the project. After doing so I attempted to get the current version of my skype.

```
package skype_tool;

import com.skype.Skype;
import com.skype.SkypeException;

/**
 *
 * @author EmorpheusXXL
 */
public class Skype_tool {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println(Skype.getVersion());
        }
        catch(SkypeException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    public static void print(Object value){
        System.out.print(value);
    }
}
```

when i run it, I get these errors.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\EmorpheusXXL\AppData\Local\Temp\JNIConnector.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
>       at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
>       at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
>       at com.skype.connector.win32.Win32Connector.initialize(Win32Connector.java:93)
>       at com.skype.connector.Connector.connect(Connector.java:328)
>       at com.skype.connector.Connector.assureAttached(Connector.java:578)
>       at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Connector.java:509)
>       at com.skype.connector.Connector.execute(Connector.java:481)
>       at com.skype.Utils.getProperty(Utils.java:132)
>       at com.skype.Skype.getVersion(Skype.java:126)
>       at skype_tool.Skype_tool.main(Skype_tool.java:21)
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621837/754604) to a similar question. The problem is your JVM is 64 bit while the api is only compatible with 32 bit. You can try using a 32 bit JVM.

Comment: thanks, how do i force netbeans to run my program using the 32 bit jvm?